# JavaFX set image throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently working on an assignment for uni where I've been tasked to develop a stock management system using Java/JavaFX.

My working directory looks like this:

```
-src
    -assets
        -image.png
    -GUI
        -viewProduct.fxml
        -viewProductController.class
```

This is the code in my viewProduct.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="adminPanelPage" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="525.0" prefWidth="514.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3f3f3f;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.banton.GUI.viewProductController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="imgProductImage" fitHeight="175.0" fitWidth="175.0" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="37.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
          <image>
              <Image url="@../productIMGs/imageNotFound.png" />
          </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label layoutX="223.0" layoutY="72.0" text="Product ID: " textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <Label layoutX="223.0" layoutY="99.0" text="Product Name:" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="223.0" layoutY="127.0" text="Product Type:" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="223.0" layoutY="155.0" text="Price: " textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="31.0" layoutY="236.0" text="Product Description:" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextArea fx:id="txtProductDescription" editable="false" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="263.0" prefHeight="71.0" prefWidth="454.0" promptText="This is where the description text will be" style="-fx-background-color: #3f3f3f;" wrapText="true">
         <font>
            <Font size="13.0" />
         </font>
      </TextArea>
      <ImageView fitHeight="107.0" fitWidth="175.0" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="440.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../assets/editProduct.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="43.0" fitWidth="59.0" layoutX="442.0" layoutY="16.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../assets/print.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label fx:id="txtProductID" layoutX="308.0" layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="187.0" text="&lt;&lt;product id&gt;&gt;" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="txtProductName" layoutX="332.0" layoutY="99.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="166.0" text="&lt;&lt;product  name&gt;&gt;" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="txtProductType" layoutX="325.0" layoutY="127.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="166.0" text="&lt;&lt;product  type&gt;&gt;" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="txtPrice" layoutX="273.0" layoutY="155.0" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="166.0" text="&lt;&lt;Price&gt;&gt;" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="14.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="117.0" layoutY="358.0" text="Total Stock Level:" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="txtStockLevel" layoutX="277.0" layoutY="358.0" text="&lt;&lt;Stock Level&gt;&gt;" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="113.0" layoutY="385.0" text="Total Stock Value:" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="txtStockValue" layoutX="277.0" layoutY="385.0" text="&lt;&lt;Stock Value&gt;&gt;" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

However, I'm trying to change the image (imgProductImage) depending on the selected item using the following code:

```
Image image = new Image("productIMGs/imageNotFound.png");
imgProductImage.setImage(image);
```

Yet for some reason, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
```

**I have tried the following:**

1. Moving the image file around the project directory - including outside of src
2. using `Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/IMAGENAME.png"))`
3. I have even copied the exact code from another student to test the functionality which didn't work.
4. using `Image image = new Image(getClass().getResource("/assets/IMAGENAME.png"))`

Therefore, I suspect it might be an IntelliJ problem?

One thing I did notice is that IntelliJ automatically shows "s:" in the `new Image` whereas, his says "url:":

["s:" in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlbMX.png)

Has anyone had any of these issues before? Any help is appreciated, the deadline is fast approaching.

Comment: IntelliJ is simply showing you the parameter name of the [constructor you're calling](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream)), so if you're using a different constructor, it's no surprise the parameter name is different. You probably need to check the build folder (`bin` or `classes` or similar: I don't use IntelliJ) and make sure the image is being deployed along with the class files. Option 4 should work, assuming you either have `IMAGENAME.png` or replace that with the correct file name.

Answer (score -1):

Just found the solution, for anyone else who has the same problem:

`Image image = new Image("file:IMAGENAME.png")`

Still not clear why simply putting the URL doesn't work but this seems to be a good solution.

Comment: it will fail in a jar - you _must_ figure out how resource lookup is working and use that